# Using a stream to iterate n times instead of using a for loop to create n items

Tags: loops, java-8, java-stream

Say I want to create n items. Pre Java 8, I would write:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    list.add(new MyClass());
}
```

Is there an elegant way to use a stream to create n items?
I thought of this:

```
List<MyClass> list = Stream.iterate(0, i -> i).limit(10)
    .map(o -> new MyClass()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a standard/better way of coding this?

Note that the *actual* usage is a bit more complex and using a stream would be more flexible because I can immediately pump the items through other functions in one line without even creating a reference to the list, for example grouping them:

```
Stream.iterate(0, i -> i).limit(10).map(o -> new MyClass())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...));
```

Comment: You think the stream will be more expressive/efficient/useful? For curiosity?

Comment: You can use an `IntStream#range(0, N)` and `mapToObject`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You could use [`Stream#generate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) with [`limit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-):

```
Stream.generate(MyClass::new).limit(10);
```

Comment: Why not `Stream.iterate` ?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq, because the state of each item is _not_ dependent upon the previous one.

Answer (score 50):

If you know *n* in advance, I think it's more idiomatic to use one of the stream sources that creates a stream that is known to have exactly *n* elements. Despite the appearances, using `limit(10)` doesn't necessarily result in a `SIZED` stream with exactly 10 elements -- it might have fewer. Having a `SIZED` stream improves splitting in the case of parallel execution.

As Sotirios Delimanolis noted in a comment, you could do something like this:

```
List<MyClass> list = IntStream.range(0, n)
    .mapToObj(i -> new MyClass())
    .collect(toList());
```

An alternative is this, though it's not clear to me it's any better:

```
List<MyClass> list2 = Collections.nCopies(10, null).stream()
    .map(o -> new MyClass())
    .collect(toList());
```

You could also do this:

```
List<MyClass> list = Arrays.asList(new MyClass[10]);
list.replaceAll(o -> new MyClass());
```

But this results in a fixed-size, though mutable, list.