# Can Stream#limit return fewer elements than expected?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If the Stream `s` below has at least `n` elements, what are the situations where the stream `sLimit` may have less than `n` elements, if any?

```
Stream sLimit = s.limit(n);
```

---

Reason for the question: in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28082107/829571), I read that:

> Despite the appearances, using `limit(10)` doesn't necessarily result in a `SIZED` stream with exactly 10 elements -- it might have fewer.

Comment: I think Stuart meant that statement in a conceptual sense. As in, it makes more sense to use a `Stream` of a known size than to attempt to take `N` from a `Stream` whose size you don't know. I don't think there's any possibility where `limit(n)` would return a new `Stream` with less than `n` elements if the original `Stream` had at least `n` elements.

Comment: Wow, I step away for an hour and you guys are all over this already. :-)

Comment: @StuartMarks I didn't mean to wake you up but thanks for the clarification :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Holger's and Sotirios' answers are accurate, but inasmuch as I'm the guy who made the statement, I guess I should explain myself.

I'm mainly talking about [spliterator characteristics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#characteristics--), in particular the `SIZED` characteristic. This is basically "static" information about the stream stages that is known at pipeline setup time, but before the stream actually executes. Indeed, it's used for determining the execution strategy for the stream, so it has to be known before the stream executes.

The `limit()` operation creates a spliterator that wraps its upstream spliterator, so the `limit` spliterator needs to determine what characteristics to return. Even if its upstream spliterator is `SIZED`, it doesn't know the exact size, so it has to turn off the `SIZED` characteristic.

So if you, the programmer, were to write:

```
IntStream.range(0, 100).limit(10)
```

you'd say *of course* that stream has exactly 10 elements. (And it will.) But the resulting spliterator is still not `SIZED`. After all, the `limit` operator doesn't know the difference between the above and this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 1).limit(10)
```

at least in terms of spliterator characteristics.

So that's why, even though there are times when it seems like it ought to, the `limit` operator doesn't return a stream of known size. This in turn affects the splitting strategy, which impacts parallel efficiency.

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstood the statement. If the `Stream` has at least `n` elements and you invoke `limit(n)` on it, it will have exactly `n` elements but the `Stream` *implementation* might not be aware of it and hence have a less than optimal performance.

In contrast, certain `Stream` sources (`Spliterator`s) know for sure that they have a fixed size, e.g. when creating a [`Stream` for an array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-) or an `IntStream` via [`IntStream.range`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-). They can be optimized better than a `Stream` with a `limit(n)`.

When you create a `parallel` `Stream` via `Stream.generate(MyClass::new).limit(10)`, the constructor will still be invoked sequentially and only follow-up operations might run in parallel. In contrast, when using `IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> new MyClass())`, the entire `Stream` operation, including the constructor calls, can run in parallel.